# Drupal's "breakpoint panels" module breaks "context-modules" "menu-active-trail"

Tags: drupal, breakpoints, panels

I'm using Drupal "Breakpoints module" and the fantastic "Breakpoints panels" module. Also I'm using the "context" module for menu-active-states that can't be done simply by path or similar.

However: When I'm using a breakpoint-panels styles on a pane that contains the menu where I need the active-trail, the active-trail class gets NOT added to my menu-link. When I remove the breakpoint-panels style on the pane, everything is working fine.

I guess this has to do with the css-classes that gets added by the breakpoint panels (see the following sourcecode).

So my pane HTML-source-code (the outer wrapper of the menu) WITH the breakpoint-styles looks like this:

```
<div class="panel-pane pane-block pane-menu-menu-standard-links no-title block hide-custom-user-screen-md-min hide-custom-user-screen-sm-max hide-custom-user-screen-sm-min hide-custom-user-screen-xs-max" id="top-menu"> ...
```

And WITHOUT the breakpoint-styles like this:

```
<div class="contextual-links-region panel-pane pane-block pane-menu-menu-standard-links no-title block" id="top-menu"> ...
```

So as you can see the mandatory "contextual-links-region" class gets NOT added when using the breakpoint-panels styles. Maybe the class didn't get added cause it collides somewhere with the class-adding the breakpoint-panels module does. Don't know :/

Any hints/ideas how to solve this?